# Android OpenGL ES 2. 0 VBO Not Rendering

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, vbo

I'm in the process of trying to get a simple textured quad to render as a VBO.  When not using VBOs everything works as expected (However, for static objects, I am still updating my vertex data every frame which seems pointless, hence the switch to VBOs).

However, I must be doing something wrong, because I get nothing, absolutely zilch, rendered to the screen.

Here is the relevant code I have:

**constructor:**

```
public VBO() {

        updateVertexData();

        vertexBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();

        vertexBuf.put(vertices);

        vertexBuf.position(0);

        //Create buffers array for VBO (I'm using interleaved data so only 1 needed here??
        final int buffers[] = new int[1];

        GLES20.glGenBuffers(1, buffers, 0);

        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[0]);

        GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuf.capacity() * 4, vertexBuf, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        mBufferIdx = buffers[0];

        vertexBuf.limit(0);
        vertexBuf = null;
    }
```

**Vertex Update**

```
public void updateVertexData(){

    vertices[0]=-1;
    vertices[1]=1f;
    vertices[2]=0;
    vertices[3]=0;
    vertices[4]=0;

    vertices[5]=1;
    vertices[6]=1f;
    vertices[7]=0;
    vertices[8]=1;
    vertices[9]=0;

    vertices[10]=-1;
    vertices[11]=-1f;
    vertices[12]=0;
    vertices[13]=0;
    vertices[14]=1;

    vertices[15]=1;
    vertices[16]=-1f;
    vertices[17]=0;
    vertices[18]=1;
    vertices[19]=1;
}
```

**Rendering**

```
public void drawVBO(){

    GLES20.glUseProgram(iProgId);

    mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(iProgId, "uMVPMatrix");

    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);

    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mBufferIdx);

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(iPosition);

    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(iPosition, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 5 * 4, 0);

    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mBufferIdx);

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(iTexCoords);

    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(iTexCoords, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 5 * 4, 3);

    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

}
```

Like I say, if I strip out the VBO code and move the code from *updateVertexData* back into my draw method, then every works OK.  Would appreciate if someone could explain what I'm doing wrong here....

Comment: HI @RetoKoradi, thanks for the comment, I have just tried it without the *4 but it makes no difference, I still get nothing rendered.  Wouldn't vertexBuf however, be a FloatBuffer rather than a ByteBuffer as I have appended a 'asFloatBuffer' to the end?  Thanks.

Comment: Oh, ok, I missed that the line extended beyond the visible region, and I had to scroll horizontally.

Comment: No probs @RetoKoradi, I think I've worked out why it wasn't working :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the offset on the 2nd '*glVertexAttribPointer*' line.

**Original line**

```
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(iTexCoords, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 5 * 4, 3);
```

The 'offset' parameter (the '3' at the end) was wrong.  3 is the size of the position data (x, y & z) and this needs to be multiplied by 4 (Bytes per float). So...

**Correct Code**

```
//For readability
final int POSITION_SIZE = 3;
final int BYTES_PER_FLOAT = 4;
final int TEXTURE_SIZE = 2;
final int STRIDE = (POSITION_SIZE+TEXTURE_SIZE)*BYTES_PER_FLOAT   

//Correct line
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(iTexCoords, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, STRIDE, (POSITION_SIZE*BYTES_PER_FLOAT));
```